# How to guarantee ProjectReferece will respect imported targets/props in referenced project

Tags: msbuild

I have two projects, A.csproj and B.csproj, where B is referenced by A by ProjectReference. And B imports a common targets/props file C. The overall reference chain is like

A -(**ProjectReference**)-> B -(Import)-> C

The problem is that:

Items/properties defined in C are not visible to targets defined in A.

However, if I change the chain to A -(**Import**)-> B -(Import)-> C, those items/properties are visible to targets defined in A.

Please note that this is a quite common scenario, where B installs a fundamental nuget pacakge containing extra properties/items, later A depends on B to achieve high level functionality and doesn't need to install nuget package again.

EDIT1: add an example of project A,B and package C
folder structure as follows:

```
<ROOT>--A--A.csproj
--------B--B.csproj
--------packages--C--build--C.props
----------------------------C.targets
---------------------lib--a.ini
--------------------------b.ini
```

**A.csproj**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!--
    <Import Project="..\B\B.csproj" />
    -->
    <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\B\B.csproj">
    <Project>{20129E3E-FE37-4BEF-81A9-DA8F3AA7764B}</Project>
    <Name>B</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="in A, This is my list of MyPackageSourceFilesProperty: $(MyPackageSourceFilesProperty)"/>
    <Message Text="------" />
    <Message Text="in A, This is my list of BingoInB: %(BingoInB.FileName)"/>
    <Message Text="------" />
    <Message Text="in A, This is my list of MyPackageSourceFiles: %(MyPackageSourceFiles.FileName)"/>
    <Message Text="------" />
    <Message Text="in A, This is my list of ini files: %(Content.FileName)"/>
    </Target>
    </Project>
```

**B.csproj**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="..\packages\C\build\C.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\C\build\C.props')" />
    <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="in B, This is my list of MyPackageSourceFilesProperty: $(MyPackageSourceFilesProperty)"/>
    <Message Text="------" />
    <Message Text="in B, This is my list of MyPackageSourceFiles: %(MyPackageSourceFiles.FileName)"/>
    <Message Text="------" />
    <Message Text="in B, This is my list of ini files: %(Content.FileName)"/>
    </Target>
    <Import Project="..\packages\C\build\C.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\C\build\C.targets')" />
    </Project>
```

**C.targets**:

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
    <MyPackageSourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\lib\net45\*.*" />
    <Content Include="@(MyPackageSourceFiles)">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

**C.props**:

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <MyPackageSourceFilesProperty>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\lib\net45\*.*</MyPackageSourceFilesProperty>
    </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

Comment: Please be a little more specific to your use case, e.g. provide a reproducible sample. Are you trying to import files that later aren't copeid to A's output? Are you expecting NuGet package content to be transitive? are you using new SDK-style csproj (.NET Core / Standard) or classic csproj?

Comment: @MartinUllrich, the goal is to copy files(in package C) copied to A's output

Comment: Have you looked at using NuGet contentFiles and PackageReference (instead of packages.config) instead? this gives you transitive behaviour. i'll need to look at it in more detail later but the items should end up in the output if you reference a project and it has copytooutputdirectory content.